# Combining the meta description and Open Graph Protocol description into one tag

Tags: html, tags, header, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to combine the meta description and Open Graph Protocol description…

```
<meta name="description" content="My meta description copy." />
<meta property="og:description" content="My meta description copy." />
```

…into one when they contain the same content?

```
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="My meta description copy." />
```

Comment: nice question, sir! You probably need to change accepted answer as second one is better.

Comment: May I ask... why would you think its important to do this?

Comment: @Nathan to reduce duplication and page weight

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them. To test it, I made the simple HTML page below, uploaded it to a server, then ran the page through Facebook's [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/). It reported no warnings related to the description tag (only about the missing `og:image` tag) and correctly read the description.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" property="og:description" content="My meta description copy." />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Test page" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/ogtest.html" />
    </head>
    <body>
    Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that, if the `og:url` value is different to the current page url, Facebook will look for a description on that url instead of the current one and ignore the current page's description tag.

It might also interest you to know that, even though it's possible to combine the two description tags, Facebook doesn't do this on their own website.

Comment: Can anyone think of any disadvantages of combining the two?

Comment: Wow, what a great idea! I've always hated the idea of duplicating that text/code at the top of the HTML document.  Of course, this assumes that you want the same description to show up on a search result page OR social media site... which is probably the vast majority case.

Answer (score 11):

Some additional info on why this is possible/allowed:

HTML+RDFa 1.1 extends HTML5’s `meta` element.

[HTML+RDFa 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax) (W3C Recommendation) defines:

> If the RDFa @property attribute is present on the meta element,
>   neither the @name, @http-equiv, nor @charset attributes are required
>   and the @content attribute MUST be specified.

So when using RDFa's @property the name is not required but it is not forbidden either, making

```
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="great description">
```

perfectly ok according to spec.

I found this from the answer to this related question: [Is it possible to use the same meta tag for opengraph and schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401085/possible-to-use-the-same-meta-tag-for-opengraph-and-schema-org)