# What's the difference between meta name and meta property?

Tags: html, metadata, meta

Two common `meta` element attributes are:

```
<meta name="" content="">
```

and

```
<meta property="" content="">
```

what is the difference between meta name and meta property?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The `name` attribute is the "usual" way for specifying metadata in HTML. It’s [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-name).

The `property` attribute comes from [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).

RDFa 1.1 extends HTML5 so that [it’s valid to use `meta` and `link` elements in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633), as long as they contain a `property` attribute.

You can use both ways, HTML5’s `name` and RDFa’s `property`, [together on the same `meta` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669).

Note that you might also see [`meta` elements with an `itemprop` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669). That would be from [Microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29).

Comment: Google is giving advice for duplicated meta tags. And its counting the `property="og:dscription"` and `name="description"` attributes as the same

Comment: Is it Frondor's argument true?

Comment: @Pascut: Discussing the behaviour of Google’s search engine is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You could create a question on [webmasters.se] asking about it.

Comment: When using the meta viewport tag, please use name instead of property. Property doesn't work in every browser.

Comment: @PieterMoeyersons: Using `viewport` as value for the `property` attribute would mean something totally different from using it as value for the `name` property; it’s not that some browsers support it like that and some don’t (at least, it should not be), and browsers typically don’t use RDFa anyway (it’s for RDFa parsers, browser add-ons, etc.).

Comment: I have noticed that the [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) ignores `name|value` and `name|content` tags – it only works specifically with `property|content`.

Comment: Is it good if I include the two attribute? The <meta name = "description"> and <meta property = "og:description"?

Comment: @sack: It’s allowed, yes, but if they have the same value, you could also use *one* `meta` element: `<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="">`

Comment: @unor Is that why Open Graph protocol used `property` instead of `name`? So we could use both attributes in the same `meta` element?

Comment: @mrmowji: I don’t think that this was the primary reason. They use RDFa most likely because it’s the right tool for the job (providing RDF-based structured data in HTML), and with it comes the feature of re-using existing HTML elements, but that’s not the only feature.

Comment: Giving that these comments report that i.e. viewport should rather use `name`, but other situations even rightout ignore `name`, is there reliable documentation about when to use what attribute?

Comment: When I was using only `name="og:image"`, LinkedIn would just get some random image from the page, sometimes even selected an icon. Now that I use both (`name="image" property="og:image"`) it gets the right image.