# What are valid keywords for meta tag's name values?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I study on w3school, one page says that only bellow values are valid:

> application-name
>   author
>   description
>   generator
>   keywords

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

But when look in some sites, such as SO or github, they use different values "og:description",...
[image]

Can anyone help with some details? Thanks

Comment: That is facebook open graph meta

Answer (score 1):

**Og** stands for Open Graph (not original gangster :)), please refer to the Open Graph protocol's webite http://ogp.me/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can only use metadata names (i.e., values for the `name` attribute) that are [1) **defined in the spec** or 2) **registered in the wiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669).

The `meta` element you are highlighting is not using a metadata name (no `name` attribute) but RDFa (that’s where the `property` attribute [comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418095/1591669)). So it’s not a classical "meta tag", and it will only be used by RDFa parsers.

It can have any property from a [vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) as value. Example vocabularies are [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) and, like used in your case, the [Open Graph Protocol](http://opengraphprotocol.org/).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it contains a lot of information. So benefit of new extensions is for machine parers, such as search engine, right?