# meta name="og:title" VS meta property="og:title"?

Tags: html, seo

I'm actually creating SEO properties for a website owned by the company I work.

http://animoetc.com

I attempted to create OpenGraph entries that work with Facebook and other social stuff. But I've used `meta name="og:__"`, that **seems to work**, but now I'm confused because many sites use `meta property="og:__"` instead.

So, is there a difference between both?

That question did not help me much: [Whats the difference between meta name and meta property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question may be answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property

Comment: I strongly disagree with this being closed as off-topic. The reason given is that this question does not "directly involve programming". This question absolutely does directly involve programming! It's a precisely defined question: does `name="og:title"` cause any difference in behavior compared to `property="og:title"`?

Answer (score 5):

The `meta property` is a standard defined in [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/), the other is a simple HTML attribute – [see this](http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags) – that all search engines recognize, and its value does not need to start with the structure `og:` (which it is precisely the acronym of *Open Graph*).