# Fetching Open Graph meta tags from a react-helmet site

Tags: php, reactjs, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

I have a script that grabs Open Graph meta tags from a remote page. I'm using PHP to load the page into a DOM document and pulling out the tag content like this:

```
if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image')
    $og_image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
```

That works great for a typical page where the tags are (to my understanding) formatted correctly, like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

But I'm running into a site (pitchfork.com) where the OG tags are formatted this way:

```
<meta data-react-helmet="true" name="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.jpg"/>
```

Of course, my code misses these because it's looking for the property, not the name.

I don't know anything about React or react-helmet, but is this proper code? Do the tags in all react-helmet sites look this way? Should I be rewriting my code to account for this? If so, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: _“but is this proper code?”_ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property