# Preview Links on Blazor Hosted WebAssembly not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a website that contains recipes etc and links are being shared on Facebook quite often.  However, the preview links are not showing the pages image and title correctly.

The application is a Blazor Webassembly Hosted solution. I have followed the directions here on this link

[Control  content in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

And it is still not working. Here is what I have done.

Client Project:

Program.cs - Added to Main()

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

index.html - Added to

```
<title>BBQFriend - BBQ Recipes, Cook Logs and More.</title>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="BBQFriend.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.bbqfriend.com/Logos/IconBackground.png" />
    <meta name="description" content="A complete BBQ recipe designer and journal. Helping you cook your very best, every time." />
```

Server Project:

_Layout.cshtml -

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />

    <title>BBQFriend - BBQ Recipes, Cook Logs and More</title>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="BBQFriend.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="_content/BBQFriend.Components/Logos/BBQFriend.svg" />
    <meta name="description" content="A complete BBQ recipe designer and journal. Helping you cook your very best, every time." />
```

_Host.cshtml -

```
 <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />

    <title>BBQFriend - BBQ Recipes, Cook Logs and More.</title>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="BBQFriend.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.bbqfriend.com/Logos/IconBackground.png" />
    <meta name="description" content="A complete BBQ recipe designer and journal. Helping you cook your very best, every time." />
```

Blazor Component Razor

```
<PageTitle>BBQFriend - @Recipe?.Name by @Recipe?.UserName</PageTitle>
<HeadContent>
    <meta name="og:title" content="BBQFriend - @Recipe?.Name by @Recipe?.UserName">
    <meta name="og:description" content="@Recipe?.Description">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Recipe?.PhotoUrl))
    {
        <meta name="og:image" content="@Recipe?.PhotoUrl">
    }
    else
    {
        <meta name="og:image" content="https://www.bbqfriend.com/Logos/IconBackground.png">
    }
</HeadContent>
```

Every time I post a link like this one https://www.bbqfriend.com/Recipe/BBQFriend/Smoked-Chicken-and-Chimichurri- the Preview on FaceBook does not show an Image and only shows the default title of "BBQFriend - BBQ Recipes, Cook Logs and More."

What I am looking for is the preview to have the Recipes Title and Recipes Photo.  What am I missing?

Comment: That link talks about setting up the Headoutlet.   WebAssemblyPrerendered will only work when you set up PreRendering first. See https://andrewlock.net/enabling-prerendering-for-blazor-webassembly-apps/ or https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/

Comment: I have preredner setup already.   In my body of _Host.cshtml i have the typeof(App) render-mode set to WebAssemblyPreRendered

Comment: OK, and does it (PreRendering) work?

Comment: If `https://www.bbqfriend.com/Logos/IconBackground.png` actually existed, instead of resulting in a 404 - that would probably be helpful here ...

Comment: Thats a fallback image and not the URL of the image that is within the recipe and that should be in the <Head>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your rendered page vs the sample code you provided, note that on your _Host.cshtml, _Layout.cshtml and index,html pages you are rendering:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="...">
```

But on your Blazor Component Razor you are rendering

```
<meta name="og:image" content="...">
```

So, you are effectively renedering both <meta property="og:image" ...> and <meta name="og:image" ...>

Facebook seems to be favor <meta property="og:image" ...> vs <meta name="og:image" ...>

OpenGraph [website](https://ogp.me/)'s examples uses

```
<meta property="og:image" ...>
```

Here's another answer explaining the difference between both:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418095/22600206

You should update your Blazor Component to use <meta property="og:image" ...>.

It is also a good idea to have an actual fallback image.

After you make the change, test it using Facebook's Sharing Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbqfriend.com%2FRecipe%2FBBQFriend%2FSmoked-Chicken-and-Chimichurri-