# Meta tags allowed under head section?

Tags: php, facebook, metadata, meta

I am working on Facebook share functionality and I want site description to include in meta tags so that it will display when I share info on Facebook.

Now I want to display dynamic description for different page which I need to include in meta tags and for that I need to put my dynamic code below head section.

So my question is that,will meta tags work if I put them below head section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that you want to use the *Open Graph Protocol*.)

When you are using RDFa, it’s valid to use [`meta` elements in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633). If you don’t use RDFa (or [Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669), and possibly other extensions), it’s not valid.

This is not allowed (using `name`):

```
<body>
  <meta name="og:description" content="…" /> <!-- invalid -->
</body>
```

This is allowed (using `property`):

```
<body>
  <meta property="og:description" content="…" />
</body>
```

If you have [`name` *and* `property` on the same `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669), it should also be allowed:

```
<body>
  <meta name="og:description" property="og:description" content="…" />
</body>
```