# Using Schema.org itemprop on Facebook OG meta tags

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta, schema.org, microdata, rdfa

Right now I'm using `itemprop` COMBINED with Facebook Open Graph `<meta>` tags like the following:

```
<html class="no-js" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
   // ...
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
  <meta itemprop="name" property="og:title" content="My Title" />
  <meta itemprop="image" property="og:image" content="http://example.com/socialimage.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="url" property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
  <meta itemprop="description" property="og:description" content="My description" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
```

Is this acceptable/valid to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itemprop` is defined by Microdata, `property` is defined by RDFa. So your question is: **Can Microdata and RDFa be used on the same `meta` element?**

**Yes**, as I have [explained in a similar (but not identical) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669):

When using Microdata on `meta`, the following attributes are not allowed: `name`, `http-equiv`, `charset`. When using RDFa on `meta`, these three attributes are optional. In both cases the `content` attribute is required.

---

Note that you could stop using Microdata and use RDFa also for Schema.org:

```html
<html typeof="schema:WebPage">
  <!-- … -->
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:title schema:name" content="My Title" />
  <meta property="og:image schema:image" content="http://example.com/socialimage.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:url schema:url" content="http://example.com" />
  <meta property="og:description schema:description" content="My description" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
```

Also note that you should use `link` instead of `meta` when the value is a URL:

```html
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:title schema:name" content="My Title" />
  <link property="og:image schema:image" href="http://example.com/socialimage.jpg" />
  <link property="og:url schema:url" href="http://example.com" />
  <meta property="og:description schema:description" content="My description" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
```

Comment: I tried, this is not working for Facebook and Twitter until now. They are not parsing RDFa whitespace separated property correctly: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/rdfa-socialmedia-metadata

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will work, but just to let you know, Google's policy is to ignore hidden markup.  So, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Whole code in your Header File:
This Script Code for Schema Data:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
        {
            "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
            "@type": "LocalBusiness",
            "name": "website",
            "url": "http://www.website.com/",
            "logo": "http://www.website.com/images/logo.png",
            "image": "http://www.website.com/images/dhaka-city.jpg",
            "title": "Title of your website | website.com",
            "description": "website.com is your online business directory of Country",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "Road #21, Gulshan, Dhaka, Bangladesh ",
                "addressLocality": "Gulshan",
                "addressRegion": "Dhaka",
                "postalCode": "1200",
                "addressCountry": "Bangladesh"
            },
            "telephone": "+880123456789",
            "geo": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "23.783127",
                "longitude": "90.394359"
            },
            "openingHours": "Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 09:00-18:00",
            "contactPoint": {
                "@type": "ContactPoint",
                "contactType": "Customer support & query",
                "telephone": "+880123456789"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Schema.org markup for Twitter:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@website">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@website">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://www.website.com/" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title of your website | website.com">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="website.com is your online business directory of Country">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.website.com/images/dhaka-city.jpg">
```

Open Graph data:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of your website | website.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Most popular business directory of Bangladesh"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/images/dhaka-city.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="@website"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="Author"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="website.com is your online business directory of Country"/>
```