# Are there any differences between Facebook, Twitter meta tags?

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, meta-tags

I have been working on a project and I have a question about meta tags.

One of the tags I use for title of a content.

```
<meta name = "subject" content = "post-title">
```

I was looking for more tags than I use for adding between < head > < /head >. I found out Facebook, Twitter and so on has their own tags. So, my question is

What happened if I use each other between < head > < /head >? Is there anything wrong?

```
<meta name = "subject" content = "post-title">
<meta property = "og:title" content="post-title" />
<meta name = "twitter:title" content="post-title">
```

As you know search engines care about the meta tags. Does Google send me to sandbox if I use these three similar meta tags?

Comment: I think you can safely assume that Google is smart enough to recognize this as what it is – not duplicate information, but the same information served in different formats for different “consumers” according to their own specific rules and specifications. After all, Google has their own way of how _they_ want to be presented with certain types of meta data, and even offers their own [checking tool](http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

Comment: Good to hear. I am newbie and I don't know the details exactly. Your answer made my mind clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML5 doesn’t restrict how many [`meta`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) elements you may have.**
We can never know for sure what specific consumers (like search engines) would like to see or how they handle it (and discussing this is off-topic on Stack Overflow), but there is no reason to assume that they’d have a problem with this.

**In HTML5 you may only use [metadata names that are defined or registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669).**
You’ll see that `subject` is not a valid metadata name.

In your specific example, you could omit one `meta` element, as you are using RDFa for `og:title`, and you can have a metadata name (in `name`) and an RDFa property (in `property`) [on the same `meta` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669):

```
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" content="post-title">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add your content and check it live then copy the tags to your website using metatags, check it out here https://www.techjournal.ai/metatags

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).