# SEO META TAG og:description vs description

Tags: html, seo, meta

I'm trying to get my site to rank on Google Search. I've searched the whole web, literarily on how to make this work. I see that when I search, it doesn't use the description meta tag. When I look at my source code it uses both og:description and description, does this cause any type of issue? Should it be de-duplicated as many tutorials suggests?

```
 <meta name="description" content="ELDE Cosmetics creates natural, fun and minimalistic skin care products for all skin types. Free from fragrance, essential oils, parabens.">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Beauty, skincare, makeup, fragrance, perfume" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://eldecosmetics.com/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">



  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:title" content="ELDE Cosmetics — Natural &amp; Organic Skin Care">



  <meta property="og:description" content="ELDE Cosmetics creates natural, fun and minimalistic skin care products for all skin types. Free from fragrance, essential oils, parabens.">

  <meta property="og:url" content="https://eldecosmetics.com/">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="ELDE">
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about seo

Comment: Isn't it allowed to post about SEO? I dodn't know. @JohnConde

Comment: @VemundEldegard: Only in programming contexts, but not when it’s about asking for advice what search engines prefer etc. Such questions can be asked on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about SEO should be asked on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 23):

Sorry to disappoint you, but these two tags do actually very marginally (if at all) affect SEO. They are mainly used for showing short descriptions of your page, if your site is linked on other sites. `description` may (you have no certainty) be (partially) used by search-engines, while `og:description` may be used by social media networks like facebook.

edit: using both (with useful content) won't hurt.

To combine them (Schema and OGP) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203984/combing-the-meta-description-and-open-graph-protocol-description-into-one-tag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401085/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-meta-tag-for-opengraph-and-schema-org) SO posts.

Comment: What if they have the same content?

Comment: @Nathan - Shouldn't be a problem, they are used by different crawlers/system (facebook sometimes seems to have a "fallback" to description, if og:description is not present).